# Proof relating to inverse functions and a rate of change problem.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[Proof Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjhMy.png) and [rate of change problem](https://i.imgur.com/uDf7XMC). For the first question I'm honestly not sure where to start. Does f * g = the identity matrix?

Comment: I cannot add more than two links in the original post so here is my attempt at the solution to the rate of change problem.  For the second problem, [here is my solution to 4a](http://i.imgur.com/pXrO5ef) and [here is my solution for 4b](http://i.imgur.com/Nf5X974). I'm not sure if my solution is correct for the rate of change problem.

Comment: Did you understand my solution that I posted? It seems that you are confusing some concepts in differential calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Write that $D(f\circ g) = I$, since $(f\circ g)(x) = x$.

Hence, $\text{det}(Df(g)\circ Dg) = \text{det}(Df(g))\cdot \text{det}(Dg) = \text{det}(I) = 1$ and so the determinants of $Df$ and $Dg$ are both non-zero. We conclude that $Df = (Dg)^{-1}$, as desired.

Now, for the rate of change problem, let's say part 4b, use the fact that $A = 2\cdot (\frac{1}{2}\cdot xy + xz + yz)$ and so, $\frac {dA}{dt} = 2\cdot (\frac{1}{2}\cdot (xy' + x'y) + xz' + x'z + yz' + y'z)$. Then, plug in the values.